# Can we disable dynamic mapping in elastic search from logstash config file?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, logstash-configuration

Is there any possibility to set the dynamic parameter to false in elasticsearch index using logstash config file.

Answer (score 0):

only if you manage the template yourself via something like [this here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-template), there's no other flag to do that